# Html.Partial and @section MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What's the difference between @Html.Partial, @Html.Section and @section ? When should I use each of them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very broad. You can find a ton of tutorials on the subject you asked with a simple google search. Please ask more specific questions (with relevant details about the problem). Also take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Html.Partial is to split the page into parts. The page will be incomplete without filling in the part.

@Html.Section is an (often optional) portion, usually defined in layouts, that inheritors can add content into. For example, if they want to add extra scripts to the page, there's a "scripts" section at the end of the default layout that allows pages to inject it at the end of the content.

@section is just defining the content for an @Html.Section in the child page.

For example:

```
<!-- layout page. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        Layout content.<br/>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
<!-- child page -->
@section scripts{
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
}

<div>Child content.</div>

<div>Partial content here: @Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialContent.cshtml")</div>
```

...

```
<!-- partial content in PartialContent.cshtml -->
Hello!
```

The result would be something like:

```
Layout content.
Child content.
Partial content here: Hello!
```